# Truncate Table in Azure SQL Database for Azure ML Experiment

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

In my Azure ML experiment I am using a writer to write data into a table in Azure SQL Database. However, I would like to truncate the data in that table before each insert. Is there any way that I can achieve this through the experiment itself? Any inbuilt module through which I can achieve this?

I know from sql using triggers I can achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried executing a SQL command to truncate the table?

Comment: That worked like a charm. I put the truncate statement in reader module followed by a dummy select statement.
Awesome. Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, please reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

truncate table written in reader module did the trick. 
Thanks Panagiotis